# I can't find the error in a program with a while loop

Tags: c

I'm learning how to program in C. Can someone help me out to find a problem in my code? I'm trying to write a program that change seconds to minutes and seconds (like 100 seconds equals 1 minute and 40 seconds).

That's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SEC_TO_MIN 60

int main(void)
{
    int sec, min, left;

    printf("Seconds to minutes and seconds!\n");
    printf("Give me an amount of seconds (<=0 is the end):\n");
    scanf("%d, &sec");

    while (sec > 0)
    {
        min = sec / SEC_TO_MIN;
        left = sec % SEC_TO_MIN;
        printf("%d seconds is %d minutes, %d secunds.\n", sec, min, left);
        printf("Next number of seconds (<=0 is the end):\n");
        scanf("%d", &sec);
    }
    printf("The End!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d, &sec");` --> `scanf("%d", &sec);`

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled? Your compiler should've warned you about `scanf("%d, &sec");`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh my god. I'm really sorry. It was so easy.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
I do have warrning enabled but it did not showed me any problems with my scanf :/

Comment: You are welcome, notice that repeating code (like in this case where you are calling `scanf` twice) is considered bad  style and more prone to errors (as you can see in your snippet). Take a look to the `do {...} while(...);` iterator.

Comment: With an error such as a missing `"` or `#endif` or `}` the compiler can't easily tell exactly where it was supposed to be, so you can get an unusual or irrelevant error report.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: I don't see how `do` ... `while` is useful here. The repetition could be removed by putting everything related to input and validation into the loop control: `while (scanf("%d", &sec) == 1 && sec > 0) ...`, which would stop on non-positive numbers, on anything that's not a number and on end of input via `^Z`/`^C`.

Comment: @MOehm  In your approach (`while (scanf("%d", &sec)`)  there is no way to check the result of `scanf`, consider `do { int error = scanf(....) != 1; if (error) ... } while (error == 1);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri: You are misquoting my approach, which does check for `scanf`'s return value and for the value of `sec`, which is what OP requires. _De gustibus_ and all that, but I find your approach with an additional variable and an additional if and therefore an extra level of indentation inferior.

Comment: @MOehm I'm not misquoting, you can check it, but you can not inform (i.e. `puts("Write a valid number");`) using your approach, there are tons of way to solve this, my point was: do not repeat code

Comment: You may want to select a more helpful compiler.  Even without enabling any extra warnings, gcc warns about this code: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]`

Comment: Oh, you are suggesting error handling of the input? Sure, that would be good, but the original post didn't have that, either and it would probably be a bit too much for such a small program That's the big issue with C training: You want to teach algorithms but you end up arguing about `scanf`. `:(`

Comment: @MOehm ... you are right and I didn't pay attention to this: OP is not checking for errors (OP: you should, even in short snippets), personally I prefer a `do .. while` than a `while(1)` or a `for(;;)` in those cases, even if its more verbose, it makes clear that it must runs at least once.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Sorry for not understanding what you intended in your initial comment. In principle, I agree with you about checking the input for errors, but for such a small program, I think "accept input while it's valid, then stop" is valid. Sorry again for starting a slew of comments that won't halp the OP at all.

Comment: @MOehm C'mon, is there a better way to pass the quarantine? :)

Answer (score 1):

Because code was not compiled with a good compiler with warnings all enabled. Example: "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int*'
so if you replace

```
scanf("%d, &sec");
```

to be

```
scanf("%d", &sec);
```

it will works successfully

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem of while but the solution is simple
check out the scanf statement before the while
i.e

```
scanf("%d",&sec);
```

reason why that problem came is to read a value through scanf function u use the format specifier %d for signed integer that u r going to allocate a value and that value is stored in the variable sec so while coding  always be care full about the inverted commas. it cannot be used where address is specified.